# SQL Server : max date from two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to find the last time a customer ordered an item for all customers and all items. I figured I would start with the last time the customer ordered anything. This would involve two tables `oeordhdr_sql` and `oehdrhst_sql` both have `cus_no` and `ord_dt`.

I am getting an error on the `on`

```
select 
    arcusfil.cus_no, Order_Date.orddt
from 
    arcusfil_sql arcusfil
join 
    (SELECT 
         cus_no, MAX(MaxDate) AS orddt 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              cus_no, MAX(ord_dt) AS MaxDate 
          FROM 
              oeordhdr_sql 
          GROUP BY
              cus_no

          UNION

          SELECT 
              cus_no, MAX(ord_dt) AS MaxDate 
          FROM 
              oehdrhst_sql 
          GROUP BY 
              cus_no) Order_date ON arcusfil.cus_no = Order_date.cus_no
```

Comment: Once I have the above query working I will need to add in oeordlin_sql.item_no and oelinhst_sql.item_no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)` before the `ON` to close the inner table that you're using for the `JOIN`

```
select 
    arcusfil.cus_no, Order_Date.orddt
from 
    arcusfil_sql arcusfil
join 
    (SELECT 
         cus_no, MAX(MaxDate) AS orddt 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              cus_no, MAX(ord_dt) AS MaxDate 
          FROM 
              oeordhdr_sql 
          GROUP BY
              cus_no

          UNION

          SELECT 
              cus_no, MAX(ord_dt) AS MaxDate 
          FROM 
              oehdrhst_sql 
          GROUP BY 
              cus_no) MaxDates
    ) Order_date ON arcusfil.cus_no = Order_date.cus_no
```

I like to use CTE's for queries such as this to keep things cleaner:

```
;WITH MaxDates AS (
     SELECT cus_no, MAX(ord_dt) AS MaxDate 
     FROM oeordhdr_sql 
     GROUP BY cus_no
     UNION
     SELECT cus_no, MAX(ord_dt) AS MaxDate 
     FROM oehdrhst_sql 
     GROUP BY cus_no
),
Order_Date AS (
    SELECT cus_no, MAX(MaxDate) AS orddt 
    FROM MaxDates
    GROUP BY cus_no
)
SELECT arcusfil.cus_no, Order_Date.orddt
FROM arcusfil_sql arcusfil
INNER JOIN Order_Date on arcusfil.cus_no = Order_date.cus_no
```

Comment: The first query gives me an error on the ')' in the last line;

Comment: The second query returns: Column 'MaxDates.cus_no' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Can you tell me what a CTE is?

Comment: @RInzana Sorry, fixed them.  CTE = Common Table Expression.  It's another syntax for "subqueries" that I think cleans up the query a bit.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx